# SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above - drupal mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, drupal

As the question suggests, I am facing the mentioned error while running drupal on mac (not containerized), I found similar questions but with different environments (python / windows / debian / docker / etc ..)

environment details are as follows:

postgres version : 10.22

php version : 7.4

libpq.pc ver : 9.3

The solution I was thinking about is to replace the libpq with newer version but not sure how (I am relatively new to mac)

Any suggestions on:

1- how to get later libpq.pc version?

2- is it safe to just replace the existing with it?

3- any other solution for this specific environment setup?

Comment: I cannot teach you how to replace a file on MacOS.... But perhaps upgrading PHP will give you a more recent libpq.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the comment, PHP 8 with mac still uses the same lib as well and even it is not feasible to update it as the whole team uses 7.4, update is not always a correct solution u know ... the question is, from where can I get updated libpq.pc file, I will then manage to replace it